# File Transfer using winsock

Tags: delphi, winsock

I want to send files(text or binary) through `winsock`,I have a buffer with 32768 byte size, In the other side  the buffer size is same,But when the  packet size <32768  then i don't know how determine the end of packet in buffer,Also with binary file it seems mark the end of packet with a unique character is not possible,Any solution there?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fixed-size "packets," we would usually that every packet except the last will be completely full of valid data. Only the last one will be "partial," and if the recipient knows how many bytes to expect (because, using Davita's suggestion, the sender told it the file size in advance), then that's no problem. The recipient can simply ignore the remainder of the last packet.

But your further description makes it sound like there may be *multiple* partially full packets associated with a single file transmission. There is a similarly easy solution to that: Prefix each *packet* with the number of valid bytes.

You later mention `TCustomWinSocket.ReceiveText`, and you wonder how it knows how much text to read, and then you quote the answer, which is that it calls `ReceiveBuf(Pointer(nul)^, -1))` to set the length of the result buffer before filling it. Perhaps you just didn't understand what that code is doing. It's easier to understand if you look at that *same* code in another context, the `ReceiveLength` method. It makes that same call to `ReceiveBuf`, indicating that when you pass -1 to `ReceiveBuf`, it returns the number of bytes it received.

In order for that to work for your purposes, you cannot send fixed-size packets. If you always send 32KB packets, and just pad the end with zeroes, then `ReceiveLength` will always return 32768, and you'll have to combine Davita's and my solutions of sending file and packet lengths along with the payload. But if you ensure that every byte in your packet is always valid, then the recipient can know how much to save based on the size of the packet.

One way or another, you need to make sure the sender provides the recipient with the information it needs to do its job. If the sender sends garbage without giving the recipient a way to distinguish garbage from valid data, then you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always send file size before you start file transfer, so you'll know when to stop writing to file.

Comment: I'll try it,I was looking for a solution to determine it in other side without changing sender side

Comment: oh Hang up,It's not possible to determine the packet size before sending it,The SendBuff method return the amuntsent after sending the packet,also i  tried to cpauter the packet in other side and waiting for the packet size to coming but it'll be too complex and seems not possible

Comment: The Socket.ReciveText determine the packet size and actual data but i don't know how =>   
function TCustomWinSocket.ReceiveText: string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, ReceiveBuf(Pointer(nil)^, -1));
  SetLength(Result, ReceiveBuf(Pointer(Result)^, Length(Result)));
end;

Comment: You don't know packet size but you know file size right? before sending the file, send file size. The client will know how many bytes it should write to the file. When the client receives the packet, store it in memory, get it's length, and if already received packets size + current packet size > file size, then write File size - already received packets size. Hope you understand :)

Comment: I understand, i have the file size but see: the buffer look like this

Comment: I understand, i have the file size but see: the Write method will write hole length of buffer not actual data for example if the  buffer  be 'abcd#0#0#0#0#0' it should know just abcd is the actual data,the problem :when filling the  byte array buffer  with zero and then when the packet coming into it sometimes the packet size<buffer size and write method will write hole buffer,

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. could you be more descriptive please?

Comment: i mean we should know the recived packet size

Comment: Joe, when you fill the byte array buffer with received data, you can get it's length by Length() function provided by delphi. Then you can write the amount of data you wish in the file, using TFileStream or any other way. Is this what you meant?